# How to generate notification when a new picture is taken by camera app?

Tags: android, android-notifications, intentfilter, android-camera-intent, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to create a notification from my app when a new picture is taken from the camera app. I want to achieve this when my app is not running. I am using Broadcast receiver to do this.
Here is my Code...

In Android Manifest..

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receivers.CameraEventReceiver"
    android:label="CameraEventReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE" />

        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In my receiver class

```
public class CameraEventReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("CHANNEL_ID", "my channel name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "CHANNEL_ID")
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Picture Taken")
                    .setContentText("here is the uri : "+intent.getData())
                    .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
                builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
            }

            manager.notify(222, builder.build());
        }
    }
```

It is working fine for Android 6.0 when the app is running...
But it is not working for newer versions. **What can I do to achieve this?** 
I want it to support for all devices with android versions greater than 4.1 (JELLY_BEAN)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using notification channels for latest versions of android, refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590489/how-to-show-a-notification-on-oreo/49594694#49594694

Answer (score 0):

> But it is not working for newer versions.

Correct. Those broadcasts are no longer supported. See [the Android 7.0 release notes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#bg-opt).

> What can I do to achieve this?

Take the picture yourself, whether using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, the camera APIs, or libraries (e.g., Fotoapparat, CameraKit-Android).

There is no direct replacement for that broadcast, and there was no requirement for camera apps to trigger that broadcast anyway.

You could use [`JobScheduler` and `addTriggerContentUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#addTriggerContentUri(android.app.job.JobInfo.TriggerContentUri)) to monitor the `MediaStore` for changes. However, I do not know how you would limit it to only pictures taken by a camera app.

Comment: But in this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#ACTION_NEW_PICTURE document. They said that **"In Android O this broadcast has been brought back, but only for registered receivers"** .. So it is supposed to  work on Android O right?

Comment: @user9333500: By "registered receivers", I believe that they mean registered at runtime via `registerReceiver()`. That will not work when your process is not running.

Comment: I tried using registerReceiver() at runtime in my Activity, but it was still not working.

Comment: @user9333500: Then perhaps the documentation is wrong. Or, perhaps the camera app on that particular device does not trigger this broadcast. Please bear in mind that there are hundreds of camera apps. There is no requirement for any of them to trigger this broadcast.

Comment: Yeah. That's right... I tried using the default Camera app. Anyway, thanks for your response.

Comment: @user9333500: "I tried using the default Camera app" -- there are dozens of default camera apps, across the ~10,000 Android device models.

Comment: Ok... That means some might not trigger the broadcast.. So is there any alternative solution for this... Can I do this using firebaseJobDispatcher since I need older version to support also?

Comment: @user9333500: "So is there any alternative solution for this" -- I outlined the options that I know of in the answer.

Comment: BroadReceiver not firing though registered dynamically in android pie and android Q

Comment: is the MediaStore method how GPhotos detects whenever another app has taken a picture so it can upload it to the cloud?

Comment: also, is it possible to work around this loss of functionality by specifically targeting a version of android lower than 7.0?

Comment: @Michael: "is the MediaStore method how GPhotos detects whenever another app has taken a picture so it can upload it to the cloud?" -- I have no idea, but it's certainly a possibility. There is an option with `JobScheduler` to monitor a `ContentProvider` for changes. "is it possible to work around this loss of functionality by specifically targeting a version of android lower than 7.0?" -- no.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented when new SMS arrived and i was facing the same issue. I have put below lines in my manifest file.

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED" />
</intent-filter>
```