# Oreo: Stop notification from getting removed on swipe

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

My Code:

```
mNotifyBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_status_bar)
                .setContentTitle("")
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setTicker("")
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.folderlist_bg_music))
                .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContent(remoteViews).build();
```

Working fine on other phones, but not working on **Vivo V7.**
On first swipe the notification is removed and it reappears. But on second swipe, it dismisses completely.

Comment: on swipe of what?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590489/how-to-show-a-notification-on-oreo look into

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko On swipe of Notification

Comment: i have same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53043991/notification-setongoingtrue-does-not-work-in-android-8-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**
You need to do the following way:

```
builder.setOngoing(true);
```

**Option 2:**

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

**Option 3:**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =

                     new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)

                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_service_launcher)

                    .setContentTitle("My title")

                    .setOngoing(true)  

                    .setContentText("Small text with details");
```

Comment: Working fine on other phones, but not working on Vivo V7.

Comment: Honestly, I am very much disappointed with Vivo, their OS is actually very unpredictable. Other applications are wont to be able to do the same. You need to lock the application if you want an application to work fine. Vivo generally closes the background services of the application. You may try by installing any alarm application it will behave the same. Even the alarm will not work. :(

Comment: The behaviour of the Vivo  is very uncertain for Microsoft applications as well. Even the outlook application does not work properly.

Comment: I would advise not to waste your time for Vivo

Comment: Hi @user1517153 if you feel this answer is helpful to others kindly accept it as an answer, and/or if you found it helpful kindly upvote.

Answer (score 2):

start a dummy foreground `Service` ...this will persist the notification while it's running.

> A foreground service performs some operation that is noticeable to the user. For example, an audio app would use a foreground service to play an audio track. Foreground services must display a Notification. Foreground services continue running even when the user isn't interacting with the app.

Comment: Working fine on other phones, but not working on Vivo V7.

Comment: @user1517153 it might be a poor oreo build; people complain about the display driver, too... possibly it might also have a vendor-specific notification system; eg. alike MIUI has.

Comment: this would be the support forum: http://bbs.vivo.com.cn/forum-152-1.html

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
builder.setOngoing(true); // Can't cancel your notification (except notificationManager.cancel(); )
```

Refer to this [Ongoing notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setOngoing%28boolean%29)

Comment: Working fine on other phones, but not working on Vivo V7.

Comment: Not sure, but this may help you https://www.techyuga.com/vivo-v7-common-problems/

Answer (score 0):

This is phone specific issue. Same thing works for other phones but not for Vivo phones.
OEMs shouldn't deviate from basic implementation that has been provided by stock Android.