# notification.setOngoing(true) does not work in Android 8.1

Tags: java, android, operating-system, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

```
 build.setOngoing(true);
 build.setAutoCancel(false);
 notification.flags= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

**setOngoing is not working**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

                /* Create or update. */
                 _notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("TubeMateGo",
                        "Downlaod File Notification",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(_notificationChannel);
                build = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext(),_notificationChannel.getId());
                build.setContentTitle("Download")
                        .setContentText("Download in progress")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
                build.setOngoing(true);
                build.setChannelId(_notificationChannel.getId());
                build.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                build.setAutoCancel(false);

                build.setContentIntent(_pedingIntent);

                Notification notification = build.build();
                notification.flags= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
                mNotifyManager.notify(id, notification);
            }
            else {
                build = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());
                build.setContentTitle("Download")
                        .setContentText("Download in progress")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
                build.setOngoing(true);
                build.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

                Notification notification = build.build();
                notification.flags=Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
                mNotifyManager.notify(id, notification);
            }
```

When I try to remove notification from notification bar its removed why ?

**i dont know where i am going wrong**

**[According to Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing(boolean))**

> ```
> public Notification.Builder setOngoing (boolean ongoing)
> ```
>
> Set whether this is an "ongoing" notification. Ongoing notifications
>   cannot be dismissed by the user, so your application or service must
>   take care of canceling them. They are typically used to indicate a
>   background task that the user is actively engaged with (e.g., playing
>   music) or is pending in some way and therefore occupying the device
>   (e.g., a file download, sync operation, active network connection).

Then Why Its Dismissed By User?

**EDIT 2**

This Happens in Custom OS ? Like **Vivo**

Test - RedMI note 5 Pro - working fine
Then Why ? Not working with Vivo ?

Comment: I am also having the same problem in vivo? Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @coderGtm as Raymond said in answer, do not waste your time trying to fix issues for every possible phone. but its strange since 2018 colorOS will have may update it should be fixed.

Comment: A workaround I found out is notifying the user every 3 or 4 seconds with the same notification id. That way, even if user is able to dismiss the notification, it will come back.

Answer (score 9):

In a few words, that's due to fragmentation and customization.
Probably that phone has some kind of setting to configure that behavior.

It's important to measure the impact of the issue, and give the user the necessary feedback about the problem. Beyond that, it might be an impossible task to solve.

As someone said one day: Some phones are just -trash-. Don't waste your time trying to fix an issue for every possible phone.